# How I can do calculate a response time of API with PHP 7.2?

Tags: php-7.2

I Team, I would like to know if there is away to calculate response time in some code of PHP 7.2. Because, I have a API and I want to monitoring the time of response.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "to do TTL"? Do you wan to increase timeout of some http call? It's not really clear what are you asking.

Comment: Hi @NeplatnyUdaj I am trying to say time to live, is a kind of response time.